# Псевдокласс :invalid

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Здравствуйте.

Сейчас сразу поля показывает красным, как сделать так, чтобы их показывало только при ошибочном вводе.

Вот пример: **http://jsfiddle.net/gpbtwu99/**

HTML

```
<form>
   <p>Адрес сайта</p>
   <p><input type="url" required></p>
   <p>Адрес электронной почты</p>
   <p><input type="email" required></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></p>
</form>
```

CSS

```
input:invalid {
 background: #fdd; /* Красный цвет фона */
}
input:valid {
 background: #dfd; /* Зеленый цвет фона */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

На чистом CSS это сделать невозможно. Можно сделать так:

```
input:focus:required:invalid {background-color: red; color: white;}
```

Тогда неправильно заполненные поля будут подсвечиваться только при получении полем фокуса.

Прочитайте вот эту статью:

**[Forward Thinking Form Validation](http://alistapart.com/article/forward-thinking-form-validation)**

Comment: @VenZell, Спасибо большое, а почему здесь не срабатывает? http://jsfiddle.net/xpcL3rf2/

Comment: @Alextrue, вы атрибут **required** забыли для textarea добавить.

Comment: @VenZell, Доброе утро, если я добавлю required оно будет обязательным, а мне не надо так)

Comment: @Alextrue, в таком случае, используйте javascript