# :invalid лишь после попытки отправить форму?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Недавно узнал о такой крутом псевдо классе для input как :invalid. И если к примеру поля required или тип не совпадает он может окрасить их в другой цвет( к примеру красный как у меня)

Проблема лишь в том что если я задаю *input:invalid{border: 1px solid red;}* , он изначально имеет красный цвет. ДА это логично ведь он required и поля пока не заполнены. Но возможно ли сделать так что бы лишь при попытке отправить ( неудачной) загоралось эта функция. Я думаю отловить события и при неудачной попытке лишь добавить класс. Но может есть более легкий способ
Вопрос задан только что

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Псевдокласс :invalid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/370168/%d0%9f%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-invalid)

Comment: Думаю, что другого способа нет. Можно не заморачиваться и воспользоваться, например, готовым годным плагином: https://jqueryvalidation.org/